# How to GET multiple parameters with different structure (Array and Int ,etc) in spray

Tags: arrays, get, url-parameters, spray

I want to get multiple parameters such as Array of String and integer in spray,for example:

```
http://localhost:8088/sWrite?name=book1&name=book2&name=book3&number=5&TF=false
```

I use below code:

```
 path("sWrite") {
    get {
      parameters('name.as[Array[String]], 'number.as[Int], 'TF.as[Boolean]) {
        (name, number, TF) =>
          complete {
            "ok"
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

But it's lead to this error:

[error] too many arguments for method parameters: `(pdm spray.routing.directives.ParamDefMagnet)pdm.Out`

How can i get array of string and integer in spray??

Comment: The `parameters` directive doesn't support this style. Look at the `parameterMultiMap` directive, instead: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/parameter-directives/parameterMultiMap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be used from paramString:

```
path("sWrite") {
    def paramString(param: (String, String)): String = s"""${param._1} = '${param._2}'"""
    parameterSeq {
      params =>
        complete {
          val sr = params.toArray
          val sw = tRest.seqWrite(Seq(sr(0)._2, sr(1)._2, sr(2)._2), sr(3)._2.toInt, sr(4)._2.toBoolean)
          "Sequence Write Successful"
        }
    }
```

Comment: according to the docs (April/2016), this is counter-intuitive. But the code samples in the docs don't compile! Can someone please add some light to this solution? Here is the way to do this according to the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom directive to extract multiple query parameters with the same name into a Seq[String]:

```
def multiParameter(param: Symbol): Directive1[Seq[String]] = {
  extract(_.request.uri.query.collect {
    case (key, value) if key == param.name => value
  }).flatMap {
    case Nil => reject(MissingQueryParamRejection(param.name))
    case x   => provide(x)
  }
}
```

It doesn't support all the bells and whistles that the `parameter` family of directives do, like optionality, defaults, and type conversion. But you can maybe do some of that by hand if you need to.

Anyway, using this directive to solve the original problem looks like this:

```
path("sWrite") {
  get {
    multiParameter('name) { name => // is a Seq, but you can do name.toArray
      parameters('number.as[Int], 'TF.as[Boolean]) { (number, TF) =>
        complete { "ok" }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```